# MongoDB $push operator and count characters in a name

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I've populated a database in Mongodb with the following data in a collection named people.

```
{ "_id" : 0, "name" : "Bernice Pope", "age" : 69, "date" : "2017-10-04T18:35:44.011Z" }

{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "Eric Malone", "age" : 57, "date" : "2017-10-04T18:35:44.014Z" }

{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "Blanche Miller", "age" : 35, "date" : "2017-10-4T18:35:44.015Z" }

{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "Sue Perez", "age" : 64, "date" : "2017-10-04T18:35:44.016Z" }

{ "_id" : 4, "name" : "Ryan White", "age" : 39, "date" : "2017-10-04T18:35:44.019Z"}

{ "_id" : 5, "name" : "Grace Payne", "age" : 56, "date" : "2017-10-04T18:35:44.020Z" }

{ "_id" : 6, "name" : "Jessie Yates", "age" : 53, "date" : "2017-10-04T18:35:44.020Z"}

{ "_id" : 7, "name" : "Herbert Mason", "age" : 37, "date" : "2017-10-4T18:35:44.020Z" }

{ "_id" : 8, "name" : "Jesse Jordan", "age" : 47, "date" : "2017-10-04T18:35:44.020Z"}

{ "_id" : 9, "name" : "Hulda Fuller", "age" : 25, "date" : "2017-10-04T18:35:44.020Z"}
```

Based on the people collection, I need to create a view named PeopleNames which likes below:

```
{ "LengthOfName": 8, "names" : [ "Sue Perez" ]}

{ "LengthOfName" : 9, "names" : [ "Ryan White" ]}

{ "LengthOfName" : 10, "names" : [ "Eric Malone", "Grace Payne" ]}

{ "LengthOfName" : 11, "names" : [ "Bernice Pope", "Jessie Yates", "Jesse Jordan", "Hulda Fuller" ]}

{ "LengthOfName" : 12, "names" : [ "Herbert Mason" ]}

{ "LengthOfName" : 13, "names" : [ "Blanche Miller"]}
```

LengthOfName is the total number of the characters in the last name and first name.
My approach is to first add the names into an array, the use `$split` operator to split the names and use `$strLenCP` to count the characters.

```
db.people.aggregate([
    {
    $project : {
        name : 1,
        name_array : [{$push : { $split : {$name : " "}}}] 
    }
}

,{
    
    $unwind : "$name_array"
},{
    $project : {
        name : 1,
        nameLength : {$strLenCP : $name_array}
    }
},{
    $group :{
        _id : "$nameLength",
        nameLength: 1
        
    }
}])
```

But I am receiving error saying that my `"$name_array" is undefined` Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push) aggregation operator is only available in the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-group) stage.

You can group the documents by the name length (after trimming the spaces in the name using [`$replaceAll`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceAll/)) and use [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) to add the names to the `names` array. You can then add a [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage to add the `LengthOfName` field to the documents and finally add a [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort) stage to sort the documents by the `LengthOfName` field.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $strLenCP: {
          $replaceAll: {
            input: "$name",
            find: " ",
            replacement: ""
          }
        }
      },
      names: {
        $push: "$name"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      LengthOfName: "$_id",
      names: "$names",
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      LengthOfName: 1,
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/M4XkvsIItmh)